# Taking Value From Text Box Into Total (VS - C#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am new to the C# scene, so don't really have much knowledge - This is my first project.

I am looking to create a very basic calorie counter, which eventually will include other functions.

Here's what I have so far;

[image]

I want to know how to take the value from the text box on the click of the 'Add' button - Which adds to the total value (bottom right)

I'm looking for any tips/videos to help so anything is appreciated.

TIA

Comment: Please edit your post, pasting the actual image into it rather than a link to an image. Also, please show the code you have tried so far to achieve the outcome you want and specify exactly where you are stuck so that it makes for an answerable question :)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response.  It doesn't allow me to paste images - It auto links them for some reason. I am yet to try code as I cannot find a legit tutorial or source online, thanks again for the comment :)

Comment: Weird! Usually you Control-V and automatically get the [Add Picture] button and it's a one-click! That's a big piece of the puzzle though :)

Comment: Word you may get some pushback or downvotes on the question because the site is more a 'teach 'em to fish' as opposed to a 'code-writing service'. Have you tried any basic research, perhaps a web search on _C# winforms textbox tutorial_?

Comment: Hey, not a problem - That I can understand.  I will do some more research now and see what I can find, really appreciate the interaction anyway :)

Comment: But please _do_ come back when you get into a tutorial and get stuck on something! We're just looking for that code sample and a specific (and non-opinion based) question. Thx for posting.

Comment: @IVSoftware You need at least 10 reputation points in order to post an image.

Comment: Declare a variable, of type `int`, at Form level to hold the Total calories. When the button is clicked, use [int.TryParse()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) to convert the `.Text` property (which will of type `String`) to an `int` so that you can accumulate the total calories in that variable. Afterwards, update the `.Text` property of your Label with the new total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a simple implementation for you, you could refer to it:

[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            bool Flag = Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int result);//Determine if it is a number
            if (textBox1.Text == "")//If it is null, falg takes true and skips the next judgment
            { Flag = true; }
            else if (!Flag)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Input Error");
                textBox1.Text = null;
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out int result);
            int total =result + Convert.ToInt32(label3.Text);
            label3.Text = total.ToString();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            label3.Text = "0";
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You really should NOT rely on the Label (`label3`) to store the total. The label should merely display the value of the variable holding the total. Why? With a variable declared you can do MATH and LOGIC with the value directly without having to convert it to an int first...